# Why bower packages differ from github endpoints?

Tags: github, socket.io, bower

I've installed *socket.io-client* bower package for my webapp and after some issues I've openned github page with this project and metioned that I have actually files with different content in it.

Just to make sure, I've compared all *js* files that I may need, i.e. *socket.js, socket.io.js, socket.io.min.js, socket.io-client.js* from bower *components* folder and there are no files with such contents on github project page.

Why is that? Isn't it supposed to be taken from there when installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower installs the latest git tagged release, master branch might have changed since then.